# Подскажите пожалуйста, как использовать данный код в рамках виджета MdiArea?

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, как данный код использовать в рамках виджета MdiArea? Так же будут очень признателен за напутствие, что почитать, дабы в дальнейшем не было таких глупых вопросов. В документации не нашел ответа.

```
void MainWindow::on_fontButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    bool ok;
    QFont fontStyle = QFontDialog::getFont(&ok,this);

    if(ok){
            QTextCharFormat format;
            format.setFont(fontStyle);
            QTextCursor txtCursor(ui->textEdit->textCursor());



            txtCursor.setCharFormat(format);
            txtCursor.clearSelection();
            ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(txtCursor);
    }
    else{
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: QMdiArea - не предназначен для редактирования текста, поэтому совершенно непонятно что должен делать код изменения шрифта текста в этом случае. Попробуйте сформутировать общую задачу, которую вы решаете. Чего вы хотет добиться с применением этого кода?

Comment: В QMdiArea создается текстовое окно, в котором хранится текст. Вот я пытаюсь обратиться к активному окну через QMdiArea.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
void MainWindow::on_fontButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    // Ищем QMdiArea. Это не обязан быть centralWidget, в этом случае, нужно хранить указаетль на этот виджет где-то в классе.
    QMdiArea* mdiArea = dynamic_cast<QMdiArea*>( centralWidget() ); 
    if(!mdiArea) return; 

    // Ищем активное дочернее окно.
    QMdiSubWindow * subWindow = mdiArea->currentSubWindow(); 
    if(!subWindow) return; // Дочеренго окна может вообще не быть.

    // EditorSubWindow - эток ваш класс унаследованый от QMdiSubWindow.
    EditorSubWindow * editorSubWindow = dynamic_cast<EditorSubWindow*>(editorSubWindow->focusWidget()); 
    if(!editorSubWindow) return; //Текущее дочеренее окно - другого типа. 

    // Получаем доступ к виджету текстового редактора.
    // На самом деле это строка должна зависеть от вашей реализации EditorSubWindow.
    // Это может быть доступ к публичной функции, окна, или доступ к переменной...
    QTextEdit * textEdit = editorSubWindow->textEdit();
    // или
    QTextEdit * textEdit = editorSubWindow->ui->textEdit;
    // или
    QTextEdit * textEdit = dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(editorSubWindow->focusWidget());
    if(!textEdit) return; // На дочернем окне несколько видежетов. И пользователь сейчас не в текстовом редакторе!

    // Далее Ваш код, только замените ui->textEdit на textEdit
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой объемный ответ с поясняющими комментариями.
Используя ваш пример, столкнулся с ошибкой "unknown type name EditorSubWindow " на строку:

    EditorSubWindow * editorSubWindow = dynamic_cast<EditorSubWindow*>(editorSubWindow->focusWidget());

Comment: Это класс унаследованный от QMdiSubWindow, реализующий " текстовое окно". Я не знаю как этот класс назывется в Вашей программе. Посмотрите какой объект создается в `В QMdiArea создается текстовое окно,...` .

Comment: void MainWindow::on_actionnew_triggered()
{
    QMdiSubWindow* newWindow = new QMdiSubWindow( ui->mdiArea );
    newWindow->setWidget( new QTextEdit( newWindow ) );
    ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(newWindow);
    newWindow->setWindowTitle("New File");
    newWindow->show();
}

Вот код создания окна. Если я правильно понимаю, то класс, который мне нужно использовать - newWindow, но с ним я получаю такую же ошибку.

Comment: У вас нет отдельного класса для дочернего окна. (newWindow - это имя переменной.) Поэтому промерка, что активное окно, нужного класса тоже не нужна. Проверяйте сразу `QTextEdit * textEdit = dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(subWindow->focusWidget());`

Comment: Спасибо, ошибки ушли, но при запуске программы и дальнейшем нажатии на кнопку - ничего не происходит.